# Making an array of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to make an array of HTML elements.  I have tried the following:

```
array.push(<tr>);
array.push(<input type="text">);
array.push(/tr);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What about to use quotes like this `array.push("<tr>")`?

Comment: yes possible. `array.push("<tr>")`

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes?

Comment: @BrandonDixon Perhaps because of the fact that entering that code into any browser's console or other REPL would show errors which show that the problem is? The tooltip on the downvote icon says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.". But it could just be the way the wind is blowing.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The person asking the question clearly doesn't know that, or they would have done it already.  This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Because you don't ask if it is possible to push things into an array, this is not valid on SO or anywhere else

Comment: @Brad I'm just saying what a possibility is. I do think this question is awfully basic for a site presumably targeting "professional and enthusiast programmers", but the tides of change appear to be bucking that original definition (to horribly mix metaphors).

Comment: @HereticMonkey As far as I understand it, there has never been a minimum knowledge requirement for questions on Stack Overflow.... only that the questions asked are of reasonable quality.  (Usually, the quality bit knocks out the truly simple questions, as newer programmers have a hard time even asking an appropriately scoped question, but I don't think that's the case here.  Clearly the poster knows that what they're doing should be possible and that what they've tried isn't working.  It's just poorly phrased.)

Comment: @Brad Actually, there used to be a close reason for "lacks minimal understanding" but it was removed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it is clear from the question that the original poster lacks understanding of some of the basic principles of data structures, or they wouldn't be trying to insert literals/HTML markup directly into an array.  You said he/she should user a REPL tool of some sort, but if the op knew what a "read-evaluate-print-loop" tool is, he/she would have enough understanding to figure out the answer to this question.  Perhaps those who've downvoted should inform the op of this process rather than punishing him/her for his lack of knowledge without pointing him/her in the right direction.

Comment: @BrandonDixon Downvotes are not punishment. That seems to be a common misunderstanding, and I think leads to a lot of the "unwelcoming" feelings. They are a signal to others as to the quality of the post. But I think this has comment exchange has gone on considerably further than I think is helpful, so I will bow out.

Comment: @HereticMonkey before you bow out, understand that if someone gets enough downvotes on enough questions, he/she is banned from asking further questions.  Thus, it is inescapably akin to punishment.

Comment: That's not punishment, that's helping the site avoid more such questions

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to go about this.

The first way is to store the tag as a string:

```
array.push("<tr><input type='text'></tr>");
```

Or alternatively, three different strings.

The second way is to actually create an HTML element and add it.  For example:

```
let te = document.createElement('tr');
let ti = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text'; //the syntax might be slightly different here
te.appendChild(ti);
```

This isn't really an array, but it is a similar concept.  If you want to put that element onto the body, you can use:

```
document.body.appendChild(te);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, just treat the data as a string by adding the quotes:

```js
var array = [];

array.push('<tr>');
array.push('<input type="text">');
array.push('</tr>');


console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, you can use one of the following options:

1. Insert it as a string. For example, `array.push('<tr><input type="text"></tr>')`.
2. Insert it as a DOM element, created by `document.createElement()`. This is useful when you want to insert it to the DOM after. For example:

```
var el = document.createElement('tr');
var child = document.createElement('input');
child.setAttribute('type', 'text');
el.appendChild(child);
array.push(el);
```

For more information about `document.createElement()`, see [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).